# EPSON TM-T20iii Paper Reduction

Tags: thermal-printer, epson

[image]

I have an EPSON TM-T20iii thermal receipt printer and an event ticketing system. The issue is when I attempt to print a ticket from the ticketing system to the Epson printer I get that blank space below. It is such a waste of thermal paper. What can I do to reduce or eliminate that space. I would love the printer to cut immediately after the header. Can anyone assist me on how best I can achieve paper reduction and reduce paper waste.